# Cannot get Android Market Licensing (LVL) working reliably. Almost always returns RETRY

Tags: android, android-lvl

I am trying to get android licensing to work in my first `Android` application.

I have followed the online guides and have integrated the [LVL](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html) Code using the [ServerManagedPolicy](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html#ServerManagedPolicy).

Regardless of what license test response I set in the developer console I almost always (9 times out of 10) get a [LicenseResponse.RETRY](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html#extras). Because `DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES = "0"` this is always converted into `NOT_LICENSED`

I've tried:

- turning WiFi On / Off
- running paid apps I bought (they all work!)
- unplugging the usb
- running in a vm and my real phone

I always get the same result. On the few occasions that I've had a licensed response it has not had any of the extras attached to increase the max retries. I think this is the crux of the problem - the first time I try and license I have no retry or validity period toleration in the default settings.

How can I get this working reliably?

---

Edit 1

---

Found this in the logs. Does this imply there is a problem connecting to the android market app?

```
08-18 21:12:16.071: INFO/LICENSE(10852): checkLicense
08-18 21:12:17.271: INFO/LicenseChecker(10852): Binding to licensing service.
08-18 21:12:17.281: WARN/ActivityManager(80): Unable to start service Intent { act=licensing.ILicensingService }: not found
08-18 21:12:17.281: ERROR/LicenseChecker(10852): Could not bind to service.
08-18 21:12:17.301: INFO/LICENSE(10852): dontAllow
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two things that might help you:

1. Assuming you are using the Developer Console to simulate a response, it sometimes takes more than a few minutes to refresh the response you got from previous tries. So if you simulated a FAILED response, you probably need to wait for a while before you can receive a SUCCESS response. Sometimes even rebooting your device will not help so you just have to wait.
2. The LVL mechanism has some issues and even on users' devices you might get a FAILED response when there is no internet connection for a while on the device, or some other network error. What I recommend is to have several retries on top of the LVL built-in retries as I found it can't be trusted and prone to errors. It would probably reduce the number of false-negative reports you'll get from your users...

Comment: I've not got as far as testing failed yet :-(  as for your point 2 - what kind of number of retries are you talking about? I just tried changing the default to "3" which delayed but didn't prevent the boot also, its a bit of a side question but, do you see many false-negatives?

Comment: What I meant is - don't rely on the ServerManagerPolicy retries. I haven't changed the default settings for it and just implemented a retry mechanism of my own that once I get any response that is not SUCCESS I keep trying again and again (It's currently set to 20 retries) and I still get a few false-negative, mainly because the user does not have internet connection at the time of the license verification and I don't think you can do a lot about it unless you ignore FAILED response when no connection is available.

Comment: Just saw you edit - Are you running this on the Emulator ? if so, it probably doesn't have the Market application installed and this is what you are seeing here (The LVL mechanism relies on having the Market installed to check for licensing)

Comment: No Its running on a real phone running 2.1

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that this is in your AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
```

That is required to run the check license code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I had this in my manifest already. It turned out to be lvl not very tolerant of slow network responses.  I modified the LVL source which seems to have solved it.

Comment: @Twisted Really? That is good to know! Though I suspect that is why they have the retry in there.