# LVL always calling back the dontallow()

Tags: android, google-play, android-lvl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot get Android Market Licensing (LVL) working reliably. Almost always returns RETRY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033066/cannot-get-android-market-licensing-lvl-working-reliably-almost-always-return)

My question is precisely the same as [Android CheckLicense is always executing the "dontallow" method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743430/android-checklicense-is-always-executing-the-dontallow-method) which has not been answered.

It's also related to [Cannot get Android Market Licensing (LVL) working reliably. Almost always returns RETRY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033066/cannot-get-android-market-licensing-lvl-working-reliably-almost-always-return). I have checked those answers and followed the suggestions but that does not seem to be working.

I am not sure why i always get a dontallow callback. I have added/registered a test-account on the developer console and no matter what license test response i set on the console, i am still getting dontallow. I am using a device to test where i have added the test-account as part of the accounts.

Any idea? Is this is a known issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common error I've seen people make is forgetting to upload their app to Android Market (it doesn't have to be published, but at least needs to be uploaded as a draft).

You also have to be testing using the same signing key as what was used for your Market APK. In other words, you need to be running a release build of your app, not the debug build (which uses a debug signing key).

Finally, if this is an existing application, make sure you've incremented your app's version code and requested the com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE permission, both on your local APK and the version uploaded to Market. (If you forget to do either of those, the license verification servers won't know to respond to requests for your app.)

Comment: Thanks @Trevor. I have accepted your answer. In my case, the issue was different. I had more than one user account on the device. I deleted all other accounts except for the one test account and i seem to be talking to the licensing server fine now.

Comment: That's interesting... Market should recognize all of the accounts registered on the phone. I'll pass that along to the Market team as a bug report. Thanks for the followup!

Comment: you bet. Thks for following this up with the wider audience. if it helps - i tested on diff devices - MOTWX435KT running 2.2.2 ver and Nexus One running 2.3.6.